# Cannot return value from a method with void result type

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to get a specific value from Firebase database, and I did it before, but now when I'm trying something a bit different, it says "Cannot return value from a method with void result type".

I can guess that I'm missing some programming rules because I'm a new Java programmer.

This is my code:

```
public int getVotesForEvent(final String event_title) {
    firebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child("Votes").exists()) {

                for (DataSnapshot event : dataSnapshot.child("Votes").getChildren()) {
                    String event_title2 = event.getKey();
                    if (event_title2.equals(event_title)) {
                        int count=Integer.parseInt(event.getValue().toString());
                        return count;

                    }


                }

            }
            else {
                int count = 0 ;
                return count;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

The error appears where I'm trying to return count.

After reading comments, this is my code and now the method doesn't effect the declared variable count, it keeps 0:

```
  int count=0;
public int getVotesForEvent(final String event_title) {

    firebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.child("Votes").exists()) {
                boolean flag=false;
                for (DataSnapshot event : dataSnapshot.child("Votes").getChildren()) {
                    String event_title2 = event.getKey();
                    if (event_title2.equals(event_title)) {
                        flag=true;
                        Toast.makeText(EventInfo.this, ""+Integer.parseInt(event.child("event_votes").getValue().toString()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        count=Integer.parseInt(event.child("event_votes").getValue().toString());


                    }


                }
                if(flag!=true)
                {
                    count=0;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                count=0;
            }

        }



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }

    });
    return count;

}
```

What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Syntactically you just can't return anything inside a function with return value void, but I think your bigger problem is that you are trying to transform an asynchronous method into a synchronous method and it isn't going to work like that

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener

Comment: either declare your 'count' as class variable or declare your variable as final(which wont solve your issue here) or move your inner class to a separate class.
Easiest for you now is to make it class variable

Comment: @RusheelJain When I make it class variable as you said, the line: count=Integer.parseInt(event.child("event_votes").getValue().toString()); doesn't effect the variable count and the value of count keeps as I declared.

Answer (score 5):

In java method with `void` means that method return nothing.

`onDataChange` return type is `void`, you can not return value `count`.

Remove return statement and Try saving `count` value in a field if you need it

Comment: Hi, I've tried what you said and I added my new code above, please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @GiladNeiger field is a variable declared in object scope or simply a global variable, use that to avoid final

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please elaborate or give an example?

Comment: @GiladNeiger declare variable count outside the method.

Answer (score 0):

Your onDataChange method is marked void, yet you are trying to return from it. Remove the return lines and save the value in a variable for further usage.

Answer (score 0):

As others have written, you cant return from void method type.
But i think I you are getting confused here because of following, there are two methods here in your code,

```
public int getVotesForEvent(final String event_title)
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
```

The first one will accept return type as integer (i.e. int). Other one expects no return type.

The second method is where you have written 'return count' and hence it fails.